# What info can be displayed with aux in

Tags: vw, audio, golf

Not sure if this is the right stack site but couldn't find any more related!

Anyway, I'm buying a new car next week. It has Aux in cable but not Bluetooth or card reader. My question is, will the radio/CD "display" be able to show any track info like the title? Or will it just show aux in mode or something? Also can i control it via the car system or do I have to do it through my phone ?

The car is golf 7 1.4 tsi comfortline

Comment: I am not sure what features you are getting, but [according to this web page](http://www.vw.co.za/en/models/new-golf/trimlevel_overview.s9_trimlevel_detail.suffix.html/new-golf~2F1-4-tsi-comfortline.html#/tab=3dc3b4bedf3496e97781a264bec4515b) your New VW Golf 1.4 TSI Comfortline is supposed to have a stereo system with not only the AUX-In, but also SD Card slot. Looking [at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyBUcCno_i8), which should be the same as your car, you should also have the availability of Bluetooth and USB. Any one of these should get you the info line display on your dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Aux port is simply an SPDIF (3.5mm headphone) port that turns your car stereo into an expensive set of speakers for your MP3 player. It doesn't do anything fancy like "communicating" with your device, aside from accepting incoming audio. I don't know anything about your specific car, but generally you switch your car's audio system to Aux-in mode when plugging something in and the display will show something generic along the line of "AUX".